# How to deploy GPT-like model to Triton inference server?

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, gpt-2, triton

The tutorials on deployment GPT-like models inference to Triton looks like:

1. Preprocess our data as `input_ids = tokenizer(text)["input_ids"]`
2. Feed input to Triton inference server and get `outputs_ids = model(input_ids)`
3. Postprocess outputs like

```
outputs = outputs_ids.logits.argmax(axis=2)
outputs = tokenizer.decode(outputs)
```

I use finetuned GPT2 model and this method gives incorrect result. The correct result will be obtained by `model.decode(input_ids)` method.

There is the way to deploy finetuned GPT-like huggingface model to Triton with inference `model.decode(input_ids)` not `model(input_ids)`?

Comment: Any new findings?

Comment: same question here, did you manage to find the answer?

Comment: Check https://github.com/ELS-RD/transformer-deploy